# Is it possible to put one UITableView over another UITableView in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: iphone

I know I can use codes to add UITableView one by one.

```
[self.view addSubview:tableview1];//
[self.view addSubview:tableview2];//
```

I hope to do the same thing in InterfaceBuilder, when I drag one UITableView onto another one, the new one always pushes the old one to the bottom, rather than just stays over the old one of UITableView.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a parent view that will contain your tableviews then you shouldn't have any problem. If you're trying to place them directly in a window then I could see a problem. If things aren't lining up the way you want you can always change their position via the Size Inspector or by nudging them with the arrow keys (shift-arrow key moves in 10 pixel increments).

Why anyone would want a tableview on top of another tableview escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent view should be a subclass of uiviewcontroller and your xib should have the root view as a uiview and not uitableview.

I used two overlapping table views to show two different contents on the same view, which could be toggles using a segment switch. Apparently my client requirements were vague enough that I couldn't just filter out data like how the phone app displays all calls/missed calls list.